# Node.JS wait for each parallel mysql query to finish

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I need assistance with the following: I have **4 MySQL queries** which I wish to run **in parallel** but it is essential that **all** queries **are completed** before continuing in the main function; The four queries get different parts of the data (they are structured differently and access different tables) that is then used in the main function. Namely, I used *async.parallel* (even tried adding the *await* keyword) but still ended up continuing before the final callback is called in *async.parallel*. I even considered cluster and worker threads, but each query function is too different from one another.

The functions in *async.parallel* are MySQL connection queries in the form of:

```
connection.query(q, function(err, res) { 
   if(err) { 
      callback(err, []) 
   } else { 
     // do something
     callback(null, res) 
   } 
})
```

Each function is shaped differently and this is only a reduced form for the sake of brevity. Example of the function:

```
async main_function() {
  await async.parallel({
  "1": function(callback) { conn.query(q1, function(...) { console.log("1"); callback(null, 1) }) },
  "2": function(callback) { conn.query(q2, function(...) { console.log("2"); callback(null, 2) }) },
  "3": function(callback) { conn.query(q3, function(...) { console.log("3"); callback(null, 3) }) },
  "4:" function(callback) { conn.query(q4, function(...) { console.log("4"); callback(null, 4) }) }
  }, function(err, results) { /*final callback; do something*/ console.log("Finished"); })
  console.log("Continuing");

  //continue
}
```

Expected output:

```
3
2
4
1
Finished
Continuing
```

Actual output:

```
Continuing
3
2
4
1
Finished
```

If there's an entire other method (even without async.parallel), I'm open to it. I will likely have multiple distinct parallel MySQL queries later in the function and in other parts of the program, so having a parametrized form such as with async.parallel is extremely useful.

Javascript being single-threaded means that solutions like 'a while loop that checks whether the queries are finished' do not work. This main_function will be called very often so forking will cause issues.

EDIT: The Jakub's solution is rather simple as in my program works as the following:

```
async main_function() {

await Promise.all([
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(q1 , function (error, result) {
            if (error != null) {
                console.log("mysql query error", error);
                return reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log("1");
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
    }),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(q1 , function (error, result) {
            if (error != null) {
                console.log("mysql query error", error);
                return reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log("2");
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
    }), ... // Two more times
]).then((values) => {
    data[0] = values[0];
    data[1] = values[1];
    data[2] = values[2];
    data[3] = values[3]; 
}).catch(function (err) { console.log(err); });

console.log("Continuing"); //continue
}
```

This is very crude right now, and if anybody wishes to suggest cleaner/better solutions for future programmers, go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These query functions are callback based (judging from your code), you can promisify them:

```
import { promisify } from 'utils';

async main_function() {
    const res = await Promise.all([
        promisify(conn.query)(q1),
        promisify(conn.query)(q2),
        // all your other queries 
    ]);
    console.log("Continuing");

    //continue
}
```